# Avoiding meta data when appending an object to another object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I would like to effectively add a property, which is an object, to a document (which is also an object), before I send the final document in a response to the user.

The new property I want to add basically takes the last object in an array called "history" - which is at the root of the document, and populates it to a property titled "activeStatus", also at the root of the document.

To do this I tried using `Object.assign` like so:

```
if (doc) {
  const appendedDoc = Object.assign({ activeStatus: doc.history.slice(-1)[0] }, doc);
  doc = appendedDoc;
} 
res.send(doc);
```

But I end up with additional meta data in my final doc -- including getters, strict mode status, etc.

How can I do this in a way that returns the clean document I'm wanting.

By the way, my initial document looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": <id value>,
    "type": "permanent",
    "gender": "female",
    "history": [
        {
            "endDate": "2018-10-31T12:27:17.721Z",
            "stage": "training",
            "completed": true,
            "startDate": "2018-10-30T13:41:18.714Z"
        },
        {
            "stage": "active",
            "completed": false,
            "startDate": "2018-10-31T12:27:17.572Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is the doc I want to produce:

```
{
    "_id": <id value>,
    "type": "permanent",
    "gender": "female",
    "history": [
        {
            "endDate": "2018-10-31T12:27:17.721Z",
            "stage": "training",
            "completed": true,
            "startDate": "2018-10-30T13:41:18.714Z"
        },
        {
            "stage": "employed",
            "completed": false,
            "startDate": "2018-10-31T12:27:17.572Z"
        }
    ],
    "activeStatus": {
            "stage": "employed",
            "completed": false,
            "startDate": "2018-10-31T12:27:17.572Z"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could serialize + deserialize to get the regular properties only:

```
 if (doc) {
   doc = Object.assign({ activeStatus: doc.history.slice(-1)[0] }, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc)));
 }
```

Comment: Beautiful. That's exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks, @Jonas!